# Different instances of sharedMaterials

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

I'm drawing a lot of boxes (~3k) in a Unity scene that are all instances of a prefab (simple cube).
However, each cube has a custom height and color. I believe that by changing the color, Unity creates a new instance of the material (I had a very high number of SetPass calls). This decreases my performance a lot.

When using sharedMaterial the performance (and the SetPass calls) is much better but all cubes have the same color.
Is it possible to group all cubes with the same color together for them to share one material but still use only one prefab?

Comment: You can draw all the boxes with one material and [`MaterialPropertyBlock`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html).

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip. This reduced my materials by a factor of 100 and the draw calls by a factor of 15 :D